# @media print not displaying hidden div

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I've got a form style webpage that I want to be saved as a PDF. Much of the div content I want displayed in @media print is hidden by default on the web as the user switches through tabs. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="Display1" class="tabcontent">
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="namefield">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Display Name">
        </form>
    <div id="Front1">
        <img class="layout" src="images/display_layout.jpg">
        <p class="input" id="frontview">Front View</p>
        <p class="input" id="topinsert">Top Insert</p>
        <p class="input" id="bottominsert">Bottom Insert</p>
        <div class="shelf-slot" id="ss-01"></div>
        <div class="shelf-slot" id="ss-02"></div>
        <button class="toggleview" onclick="ToggleFront(); ToggleBack ()" style="border: none; padding: 4px 10px; border-radius: 4px; outline: none; color: white;">Show Back View</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Back1" style="display: none">
        <img class="layout" src="images/display_layout.jpg">
        <p class="input" id="backview">Back View</p>
        <p class="input" id="topinsert2">Top Insert</p>
        <p class="input" id="bottominsert2">Bottom Insert</p>
        <div class="shelf-slot" id="ss-03"></div>
        <div class="shelf-slot" id="ss-04"></div>
        <button class="toggleview" onclick="ToggleFront(); ToggleBack ()" style="border: none; padding: 4px 10px; border-radius: 4px; outline: none; color: white;">Show Front View</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  function ToggleFront() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Front1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

  function ToggleBack() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Back1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

In this case, "#Back1" is hidden by default but the user can toggle between viewing "#Front1" and "#Back1", however, when the user hits the print button I want both to be displayed. I've created a stylesheet for @media print:

```
@media only print {
    * {
         -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
    #Display1 {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #Front1 {
        display: block;
    }
    #Back1 {
        display: block;
    }
    .layout {
        position: absolute;
        width: 350px;
        left: 340px;
        top: 82px;
    }
    input, select, textarea {
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #44748A;
    }
    input[type=text], select {
        width: 96%;
    }
    #topinsert {
        left: 17px;
        top: 180px;
    }
    #bottominsert {
        left: 20px;
        top: 355px;
    }
    #topinsert2 {
        left: 723px;
        top: 180px;
    }
    #bottominsert2 {
        left: 723px;
        top: 355px;
    }
    #ss-01 {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 300px;
        height: 106px;
        top: 225px;
    }
    #ss-02 {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 300px;
        height: 106px;
        top: 400px;
    }
    #ss-03 {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 300px;
        height: 106px;
        top: 225px;
        left: 723px;
    }
    #ss-04 {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 300px;
        height: 106px;
        top: 400px;
        left: 723px;
    }
    .toggleview {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Regardless of my stylesheet, the print preview only shows what happens to be shown on the webpage at the time. I've tried messing with different display values on different divs, but I can't seem to find a solution that gets both "#Front1" and "#Back1" to show at the same time. My apologies for including a lot of code, just wanted to make sure nothing was overlooked.

Comment: If you have any issue understanding my answer, if it doesn't seem to solve your problem, or if something is missing, please tell me. Otherwise I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Understanding the problem

There is a [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue with the way you are doing things.

Quick summary: specificity is what defines which style properties get applied to an element when several are competing. It's a sequence of 5 numbers represented like this: `1.1.1.1.1`. The higher the number, the "stronger" the specificity. When multiple properties are competing (like if `display` is defined in several places for the same element), the one with the highest specificity gets applied.

This is why you can do things like this:

```css
.element {
  color: black;
}

.element.current {
  color: red;
}
```

In your case, there are 2 ways the specificity of `display` is affected:

- Defining styles in the HTML directly (`style="display: none"`) will always give the properties defined that way a specificity of `0.1.0.0.0` (and adding styles in JS with `el.style.display = 'none'` adds them to the HTML `style` attribute)
- Defining styles in "normal" CSS only affects the the last 3 specificity indexes `0.0.x.y.z` where `x` is the number of IDs used in the selector, `y` is the number of classes (and other things), and `z` the number of tag names. It's a bit more complicated than that, but that's the basic idea.

[This chart](https://specifishity.com/) gives a good overview of the different things that influences specificity and how they relate to one another.

Some examples of specificity:

```css
#a #b {
  display: none; // specificity of 0.0.2.0.0
}

.a .b {
  display: none; // specificity of 0.0.0.2.0
}

#a .b span {
  display: none; // specificity of 0.0.1.1.1
}
```

The only way *in CSS* to override the specificity of a `style` attribute in HTML is to use `!important` which gives the property a specificity of `1.0.x.y.z`. So you could use

```css
#Display1 {
  display: block !important; // specificity of 1.0.1.0.0
}
```

Some selectors do not add specificity, which is relevant for your situation since *media queries do not add specificity*. For example, in the following case, `#el` will be `display: none`

```css
@media print {
  #el {
    display: block; // specificity of 0.0.1.0.0
  }
}

#el {
  display: none; // specificity of 0.0.1.0.0
}
```

In case of equal specificity, the order matters: the last property to be declared wins (within the same file obviously, but also across stylesheets: the last one in the DOM order wins).

And finally, when comparing specificity, each of the 5 numbers overpowers the ones coming after it:

- `0.0.0.1.0` will always win over `0.0.0.0.99`
- `0.0.1.0.0` will always win over `0.0.0.99.99`
- etc.

## Solution

In your case, if you need / want to keep `style` attributes in HTML, you should use `!important` to override them when necessary

```css
@media only print {
  #Front1 {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

However be aware that **you should always strive to use `!important` as little as possible** since it kind of is the nuclear option. Future devs will throw their arms in the air and curse the old gods if they ever need to artificially increase the specificity of their CSS selectors because *someone* used `!important` everywhere.